Help with proving the fundamental theorem of Algebra for complex polynomials
$\textbf{Problem:}$
Prove that for $x, a_k, b_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta, \phi_k \in [0, pi]$, that there exists a solution to the sets of equations:$$K(x, \theta) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^kcos(k\theta + \phi_k) = 0$$
$$R(x,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^ksin(k\theta + \phi_k) = 0$$
$\textbf{Process:}$
I have been trying to prove FToA: all n'th degree polynomials equal $$P(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_iz^i$$
Where $c_i \in \mathbb{C}, c_n = 1$. I've proven that if $P(z_1)=0 \implies \exists Q(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]: P(z) = (x-z_1)Q(x)$
And I am at the point, where if I can show that the equation has solutions, would imply that FToA for complex numbers is true. The equations are as follows:
$$K(x, \theta) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^kcos(k\theta + \phi_k) = 0$$
$$R(x,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^ksin(k\theta + \phi_k) = 0$$
Where the given variables fullfill: $x,a_k, b_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi_k, \theta \in [0,\pi]$. The proof would require that there exists a solution to the above equations for all values of $a_k, b_k, \phi_k$. There are also LEGAL simplifications that I've made along the way before this equation: $b_n = 0, a_n = 1$, and both $a_0, b_0$ can't be equal to $0$. I've actively tried to avoid looking at existing proofs to challenge myself based on my knowledge, so please try to avoid spoiling the proof. The visualization of where this came from is considering the output curve in $\mathbb{C}$ values taken from the input space follow a parametric form (goes a long a line centered at the origin), where  $\theta$ is the slope of that line. This set must always go through the origin if FToA holds. Ideas on how to proceed with the equation or problem?
One additional way to maybe circumvent the equation is to create the set of vectors which's dot product is equal to zero with the coefficient vector of $R(x, \theta)$ and $K(x, \theta) constructed with a normal, times a rotation matrix around the coefficient vector, and looking at the intersections of those two and the vector based on the variable part in the polynomial, but this seems beyond my own depth. But this is purely secondary if the equations turn out to be hella difficult. Any ideas on how to continue?
As a clarification to a comment: when considering the input space of a determined slope of a line in the complex plane, the input can be considered real after inserting the multiplicative inverse to the slope into the polynomial $P(z).$ Converting this to it's real and imaginary components give $K(x, \theta)$ and $R(x, \theta)$ respectively. The sum of the degrees thus comes from euler's product formula. Thus, $x$ represents the argument of the original complex value.

I think you don't mean $P(z)=\prod_{i=0}^n c_iz^i$.

@Kenta Why? A polynomial with complex coefficients and a complex input, when $n:= deg(P(z))$, what is the problem?

When $n=2$, you are saying $P(z)=(c_0z^0)\cdot (c_1z^1)\cdot (c_2z^2)=c_0c_1c_2z^3$.

whoops, I meant SUM...

Is $c_k = a_k + i b_k$, $x=|z|$ and $\theta$ the argument of $z$? Also, I'm not sure where $\phi_k$ comes from.

@red_trumpet Does the clarification help?

Why should $\phi_k=0$? Otherwise, since $a_k, b_k$ can be both positive and negative, means that all slopes of the line can be achieved.  I don't understand what you mean by $\phi_k = 0$? $\phi_k$ is the degree of the coefficient. When "making the input real", you take a subset of the input space. The coefficients are not changed, thus the degrees of the coefficients must be taken into consideration. Would an image help?
